# bootstrap popover not work in jquery load function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a specific problem with bootsrap popover.

All jquery and bootstrap files are included in file `index.php`, in this same file i have this div:

```
<div id="con"> Loadding </div>
```

And I have a jquery function which loads a content from php file

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var auto_refresh = setInterval(
  function()
  {

  $('#con').load('ajax/some.php');
  }, 1000);
});
```

In `some.php` file I have link with to activate a bootstrap popover.

```
        echo ' <a href="#" 
        class="pop-tel" 
        data-html="true" 
        data-container="body" 
        data-trigger="hover" 
        data-placement="bottom" 
        data-content="Tel: xxx" 
        data-original-title="';     
    echo    'Test">'; 
    echo 'Some one</a>';
```

the content from `some.php` will work great, but bootstrap popover doesn't show.

Can you help me?

Comment: Try to check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226851/how-to-update-bootstrap-popover-text

Comment: @zer02 thx for answer, but this not i need, i must active popover from .load content -> some.php file popover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a tooltip to, say a button, according to bootstraps documentation, you'd end up with something like this (within the external file you're using Jquery Load to return).

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip info here">Some Button</button>
```

Within your Jquery callback, you can initialize all tooltips. This is according to Bootstrap's Documentation for "opt-in" [Bootstrap Tooltip Examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips-examples)

Your callback for Jquery Load would then look like this

```
  $('#con').load('ajax/some.php', function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()

  });
```