# How to refresh/update Popover in GWTBootstrap?

Tags: gwt, popover, gwtbootstrap3

I use GWTBootstrap3 v0.9.1.

I want to display a [Popover](https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#popover)  with content that is stored in database. So when user hovers an element for the first time a Popover is displayed with `Please wait...` info. Meanwhile I get the proper text from database and want to replace Popover's content with a new one.

I thought this code would do the trick:

```
popover.setContent(newText);
popover.reconfigure();
```

But it doesn't work: the popover disappears and is not displayed anymore.

I know there are [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226851/how-to-update-bootstrap-popover-text) for Bootstrap users, but as I use **GWT**-Bootstrap I want to do it in **GWT** without using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow @Knarf's suggestion and use native method as I could not find pure GWT solution:

```
private native void updatePopover(Element element, String popoverHtml, boolean shown) /*-{
    var $popover = $wnd.jQuery(element);
    $popover.data('bs.popover').options.content = popoverHtml;
    if(shown)
        $popover.popover('show');
}-*/;
```

where:

- `element` is the popover widget's element (the element that has the popover)
- `popoverHtml` is the new content
- `shown` indicates whether popover is visible during update

I keep track of visible state by ShowHandler and HideHandler:

```java
uiPopover.addShowHandler(new ShowHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(ShowEvent event) {
        popoverVisible = true;
    }
});
uiPopover.addHideHandler(new HideHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onHide(HideEvent event) {
        popoverVisible = false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT**:
It's better to use ShowHandler and HideHandler instead of ShownHandler and HiddenHandler.

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this I just write native javascript methods that the jquery stuff to make it happen.

Even better I change it in the GWT-Bootstrap library itself and do a pull request so its get merged in the main repo.

I did something like this in the past for GWT-Bootstrap3 and it got merged in the main repo pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The subject is already answered but there is a GWT work around. The reconfigure method doesn't work well while the `isAnimated` property is `true`. Just turn it off at the initialization.