# Boostrap popover doesn't work every second time

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

If I run this (JS in console for ease):

```
<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default">Click</button>

$("#myBtn").popover('destroy').popover(
            {
                placement: 'left',
                title: 'test',
                html: true,
                content: 'test',
                trigger: 'focus'

            }
        );
```

The popover works. If I run the JS a second time, the popover doesn't work (can be seen in visual event that it doesn't bind). If I run it a 3rd time, it works. And so on...

Is this a bug in bootstrap, or am I missing something? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What 3rd party libraries are you using?

Comment: Could you try removing your destroy statement? Just use `$("#myBtn").popover({...})` instead.

Comment: @SirMcPotato underscore.js and react.js, but I tested it with only bootstrap.

Comment: @Aer0 Yes that's what I did initially, but once initialised I can't update the same popover with new content

Comment: I had the same exact problem because of the presence of Prototype which produces some bad behaviors in Bootstrap.

Comment: Well ... isn't it working properly here? https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/LxLPEm

Comment: **[This answer might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11310625/2065039)**

Comment: @Aer0 no the issue is when you run it 2*n times - try clicking activate once, then twice: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpZBjB

Comment: can you use $(document).on('popover',"#myBtn" ... maybe it works